# VBA Little Hashmap to get path problems

Tags: excel, vba

I got some problems with my hashmap, it is in .xla file (complementary macro), i explain what i want : if i call my macro with parameter (cv_source), i want the path of cv_source, here is my code:

```
Sub path_file()
    Dim path
    Set path = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    path.Add "cv_source", "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\Sources"
    path.Add "creation_cv", "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\"
    path.Add "save_chrono", "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\Sauvergardes_chrono"
    path.Add "save_chrono.xls", "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\Sauvergardes_chrono\Chrono.xls"
    path.Add "chrono2018", "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\Sources\Chrono2018.xls"
    path.Add "chrono", "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\Sources\Chrono.xls"
    path.Add "cv_pdf", "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\CV_pdf"
    path.Add "base_dates", "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\Etiquettes\Base dates.xls"
    path.Add "ariane.xls", "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\Sources\Ariane.xls"
    path.Add "import_deca", "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\Importer dans DECA.xlsm"
    Return
End Sub
```

My problems are the following : - How can I return path ? I can't put global variable for path because it doesn't work
- How can I call the macro in an other file? I selected the xla file in others excel files but to call the macro how can i do ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collection` instead `CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`

```
Sub path_file()

    Dim path As New Collection
    path.Add "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\Sources", "cv_source"
    path.Add "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\", "creation_cv"


    Debug.Print path("cv_source")

End Sub
```

You can even have public variable as collection, but you have to remember that you have to fill it before using.

____edit

You should load data once, not every calling.

```
Public path as new collection 'this is your global object (on top of module)

'this procedure should be run during exec Excel (I don't know where - in Word there is AutoExec procedure)
Public sub LoadData()

    path.Add "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\Sources", "cv_source"
    path.Add "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\", "creation_cv"
    '(...)

end sub
```

And in when You need sht from path use only this: `path("cv_source")` in code.

Comment: Ok thanks i think it's working but now i want to use this macro in an other excel file, tjis macro is in .xla file already, how can i use the macro in other file : example, i want cv_cource path in other macro in an other file ?

Comment: And for the global variable,i do "Global path as New collection" above macro or "public" but it doesn't work, it writes "the member already exists in an object module so the present module is derived"'

Comment: @MaximeFerreira Have you considered making this a `Public Function` instead of a `Sub`, which will return the `Collection` to the calling procedure?  Or, passing a parameter as `ByRef` for similar effect?

Comment: No i'm not good in vba, i thought sub was only thing we can do, so i replace sub by public function and i return path?

Comment: Return path doesn't work :  expected: end of instruction
Is there any end of onstruction in vbaz like ; in c or something else ? @Chronocidal

Comment: @MaximeFerreira VBA doesn't use the `return` keyword, instead the Function Name is treated as a variable:  [Official Microsoft documentation and example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/function-statement#example)

Comment: @Chronocidal how can i do to use my function without return?

Comment: Before `End Function` you should assign value `path_file = path(key)`

Answer (score 0):

So, no return, and how can i test in an othersub if this is working ? You think my function is good here so ?

```
Public Function path_file(path As Collection)
path.Add "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\Sources", "cv_source"
path.Add "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\", "creation_cv"
path.Add "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\Sauvergardes_chrono", "save_chrono"
path.Add "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\Sauvergardes_chrono\Chrono.xls", "save_chrono.xls"
path.Add "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\Sources\Chrono2018.xls", "chrono2018"
path.Add "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\Sources\Chrono.xls", "chrono"
path.Add "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\CV_pdf", "cv_pdf"
path.Add "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\Etiquettes\Base dates.xls", "base_dates"
path.Add "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\Sources\Ariane.xls", "ariane.xls"
path.Add "D:\Téléchargements\CreationCV\CreationCV\Importer dans DECA.xlsm", "import_deca"
```

End Function
@chronocidal